# Handle Resize for Icons in Panel , UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

How to resize the MenuBarContainer according to window Resize?
I have Group1 class which extent ContentPresenter and has 4 views (View1,View2,View3,View4).while window Resize,I need to switch the views based on the width of the Group1(ContentPresenter),(i.e, Which view is suitable for current window Size).
Maximum View is View1 and then view2->view3->view4.

My Complete [Source Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JWvGP8su-HgLBuimwKHLhBLYV5OVmr3X?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

> Handle Resize for Icons in Panel , UWP?

You  could listen current CoreWindow SizeChanged event and get the changed size, when you change current window, you could calculate current zoom value base on previous window size. And then resize your icon zoom value.

For example

```
public Icon3(SvgImageSource contentIconSource, string contenttext)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ContentIcon.Source = contentIconSource;
    ContentBlock.Text = contenttext;
    Loaded += Icon3_Loaded;
}

private void Icon3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
}
private double previousWidth;
private void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var size = args.Size;

    var windowWidth = size.Width;
    if (previousWidth != 0)
    {
        var zoomValue = windowWidth / previousWidth;
        Root.Width = this.ActualWidth * zoomValue;
    }
    previousWidth = windowWidth;
}
```

**Update**

```
private void Group1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
}

private void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var size = args.Size;

    var windowWidth = size.Width;
    if (0 < windowWidth && windowWidth < 500)
    {
        View4();
    }
    if (500 < windowWidth && windowWidth < 720)
    {
        View3();
    }
    if (720 < windowWidth && windowWidth < 1200)
    {
        View2();
    }

    if (1200 < windowWidth)
    {
        View1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually,You misUnderstand my question.I didn't want to resize the iconsWidth. I want to handle the views(View1,View2,View3,View4) based on window size. if window width is less than Group1 width, I need to change the view from view1 to view2 and so on or if window width is greater than Group1 Width,I need to change the view from view2 to view1 and so on. Do you understand what I'm asking?

Comment: Ok, I got it,  Does  [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger?view=winrt-22000)  meet your requirement ?

Comment: No.Using adaptive triggers,we can change the properties of the control while the minimum window width reached. But I need to replace the icons also while resize!.

Comment: i have updated the case that listen current core windows with in the group class then call view method when  reach specific width value

Comment: I already tried this way. But it won't meet my requirement!. What if I have a Group2 right of Group1. while resize first I need to change the Group2 view from View 1 to view 2 and then Group1 view from view1 to view2 and then group2 view from View2 to View3 and so on.If you want live example, take a look on MS-Excel menuBar icons and  how they change while resize the window?

Comment: At the same time,If I Change the Icons Laebl or localization(language) the groups width may be changed due to text in Icons. In this case, if the check like WindowWidth < 1200 / 720 / 500...It won't work well right??

Comment: Yep. I got it, it think you could render them all at first, and hide no-need items when reach specific width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241025/discussion-between-premkumar-shanmugam-and-nico-zhu-msft).